# SynonymGraphFilterFactory with ShingleFilterFactory missing original string

Tags: solr, lucene

**Synonym.txt**

Phone Case,Mobile cover,Mobile case

**Managed-Schema**

```
<fieldType name="standardField" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([\.,])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"  />
    <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" outputUnigrams="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
 
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([\.,])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Document**

```
Mobile cover
```

**Search Term**

```
Mobile cover
```

**Issue**

Not sure if this is caused by bad config of `SynonymGraphFilterFactory` or `ShingleFilterFactory` Index never having full string as value to match it. Like I never have original string `mobile cover` as a result all filters, when I search `mobile cover` I get no documents.

**Analysis**
[image]

**Update I**

I added `solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory` after `solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory` as recommended by SOLR docs, now char index looking good to me on Synonym output. But still having same issue.

[image]

Comment: There is an issue with synonym expansion before the shingle filter even comes into play (they get wrong indexes, positionLength, 'case' appears twice, etc.). I think it comes from how they are defined in `synonyms.txt`. Add to your question the relevant lines of that file (any line that contains any of the involved synonyms).

Comment: @EricLavault add lines - you mean other synonyms? I removed all lines from syn and kept just this one line as mentioned in the question. Still no luck.

Comment: Well, sorry I didn't see that line... The problem is having multi-words synonym expansion at index time, which is not possible. Only then, consequently, you have the issue with shingles. Adding the FlattenGraph filter might be useful but it won't fix the multi-words issue, only single token expansion. I don't get how you got the second screenshot though, not the fact that you changed the whole analysis chain, but it seems that synonyms.txt also changed. A filter cannot magically fix the output of the filter before it.

Comment: An alternative is to expand synonyms at query-time, which allows multi-words expansion, especially if you need to index shingles. This [article](https://lucidworks.com/post/multi-word-synonyms-solr-adds-query-time-support/) might be useful.